# How to get a nav to stack at a certain width

Tags: html, css

Im trying to get the nav to stack when the screen is at a min width of 767px.

I cant seem to get them to perfectly stack on top of each other. When i get it to that width the words just scrunch up.

This is what i have for code so far

html

```
 <header>
  
   <nav>
    <a href="/">Home</a> 
    <a href="winter.html">Winter</a> 
    <a href="spring.html">Spring</a> 
    <a href="summer.html">Summer</a> 
    <a href="autumn.html">Autumn</a> 
  </nav>
</header>
```

css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
  nav a{
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }

}
```

im not sure what im doing wrong but im trying to get it to look like this [Content stacked up and centered when the screen is a certain width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO9Ae.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!

```css
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
    nav a{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

nav{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
}

nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav>
    <a href="/">Home</a> 
        <a href="winter.html">Winter</a> 
        <a href="spring.html">Spring</a> 
        <a href="summer.html">Summer</a> 
        <a href="autumn.html">Autumn</a> 
    </nav>
</header>
```

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Do the following

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
    nav a{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

nav{
    width: 100%;
}

nav a{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav>
    <a href="/">Home</a> 
        <a href="winter.html">Winter</a> 
        <a href="spring.html">Spring</a> 
        <a href="summer.html">Summer</a> 
        <a href="autumn.html">Autumn</a> 
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `block` display, rather than the default inline display for links.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
  nav a{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For screen size less than 767px change `display` to `block` for `<a>`.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  nav a {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="winter.html">Winter</a>
    <a href="spring.html">Spring</a>
    <a href="summer.html">Summer</a>
    <a href="autumn.html">Autumn</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```